# Hiding <div> block doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have callback button and hidden callback form.
Form shows up after click on button and hide after click on any place on the screen except the form-space.
**BUT! Form don't hide on mobile devices. I think that problem is in touch tracking on iOS.**
How can i fix this problem?

```js
function showcallbackform (objName) {
    if ( $(objName).css('display') == 'none' ) {
        $(objName).animate({height: 'show'}, 200);
    } else {
        $(objName).animate({height: 'hide'}, 200);
    }
};

jQuery(function($){
 $(document).mouseup(function (e){
  var div = $("#callback-form");
  if (!div.is(e.target)
      && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
   div.hide();
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [touchend event?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)

Comment: There's no "mouseup" event on a mobile device without a mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind both actions (mouse and touch events) like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(document).bind( "mouseup touchend", function(e){
        var div = $("#callback-form");
        if (!div.is(e.target)
            && div.has(e.target).length === 0) {
            div.hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `.on()` should be used instead of `.bind()`, since `.bind()` maps to `.on()`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have been searching an answer for 7 hours!